# Setting Active Selector With No Outlines or Borders

Tags: css

I want my link's `active` state to be blue and not have any outlines or borders. However my `focus` state does have an outline which seemingly overrides the `:active {outline: none;}` property.

How do I set the `active` state so that it does not have any outlines or borders?

```
  :active {
    color: blue;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
  }

  :focus {
    outline: 2px solid green; 
  }
```

Comment: It's generally bad practice, but the `!important` postfix should solve your issue. Otherwise, you'd have to look at the specificity to see why one overtakes the other, which is not possible to see with your current code example. Also, try to change the order of :active and :focous. I.e. make :active last to see if it fixes the specificity issue.  CSS order matters.

Comment: Changing the order seemed to have fixed it and yes, I did not want to resort to using `!important`

Comment: posted it as an answer with some more elaboration. Feel free to accept the answer so that other visitors who encounter the same issues are able to quickly find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS is mainly about specificity.

1. !important postfix
2. Inline CSS
3. Most specific case (by selectors)
4. Order of CSS
5. Externally referenced styles

Changing the order here works because of the top-down rule of specificity. If both are equal, the last declaration wins.